# php: force download to hd?

Tags: php, download

```
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false);
header("Content-type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"". $file ."\";");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file));
file_get_contents($file);
readfile($file);
exit();
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Shouldn't this download any file from my server to the harddrive of the user? Somehow every file is damaged! Moreover I wonder how I can change the filename of the downloaded file?

`$file` always contains the full path to my file.
if I try `header('Location:' . $file );` the browser successfully opens my file. however if the file is a .jpg the browser doesn't prompt the download window. instead it just opens the file in the browserwindow. I want every file to be downloaded to the hd.

Please help me guys. I'm after this for over a week now and I can't find a solution?

Comment: If $file contains a path and not only the name you should use `filename=\"". basename($file) ."\";"` and what is the `file_get_contents($file);` line supposed to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use

`header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");`

Instead of "force-download"

Also why are you doing `file_get_contents` and `readfile`? Only one is needed - You are basically including the file twice which is why it's corrupted. Here is how I would execute the above code:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
header("Expires: -1");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream;");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($file) . "\";");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
echo file_get_contents($file);
```

That should be sufficient - so long as the file actually exists

Comment: I'd prefer `readfile($file)` over `echo file_get_contents($file)`. No need to read the entire file content into memory (as a string) and then echo it.

Comment: This is very true. The main issues with the script was the lack of basename for content-disposition and the inclusion of two "file reading" functions. `readfile` would probably be more suited - I've just always used `file_get_contents`