# Dynamic PHP webpage save to PDF

Tags: php, css, pdf, pdf-generation

I am creating an invoicing application that generates a dynamic invoice via php/mysql in the browser windows.  Tables and css are part of the makeup.

I was thinking it would be nice to have a button that when clicked, a popup would appear asking you to save a pdf to your computer.

Can someone steer me in the right direction?

Comment: How about : http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php ?

Answer (score 3):

These might be of help:

- [fpdf](http://www.fpdf.org/) - PHP class-based generator
- [wkhtmltopdf](https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) - Convert html to pdf using webkit (qtwebkit)
- [mPDF](http://mpdf.bpm1.com/) - PHP class which generates PDF files from UTF-8 encoded HTML
- [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/) - an enhanced and maintained version of fpdf
- [dompdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) - (mostly) CSS 2.1 compliant HTML layout and rendering engine
- [Zend_Pdf](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.pdf.html) - A PDF manipulation engine/component from Zend
- [PrinceXML](http://www.princexml.com/) - Commercial, but supports CSS3 transforms

It's partly dependent on how complex the HTML is and what you want to display. Some of them can be a bit flaky when rendering certain style-based elements (especially CSS2/CSS3), but in general they are pretty good.

If you're planning to "force-download" your PDFs, then you'll need to use something like the following in PHP:

```
  header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=filename.pdf');
```

A good example/explanation can be found in a previous SO answer: [php: force download to harddrive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314579/php-force-download-to-hd)

Comment: Not to forget PDFlib.com - Fast enterprise class-based engine for PDF-Creation

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  Here is where I am at.  I could not get mpdf to work, and it looks promising as you just call the code from within your php.  tcpdf looks promising to, however you have to re-write your php code to work with it.  Still working on testing out the other suggestions.